# Dropdown select change only if the data is not dirty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a dropdown menu and based on dropdown selection i get values in text boxes. but if i am updating any of the textboxes and then i click on dropdown and change the value without clicking the save button it should not allow to change the value.

```
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router, private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService, private _http: AsyncHttpService, private _logger: AppLoggerService,
    private confirmationDialogService: ConfirmationDialogService, private _alertService: AlertService, private _messageService: MessageService) { }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  browserCanActivate($event) {
    if (this.isDataChanged == true) {
      $event.returnValue =
        this._messageService.warningChangesNotSaved;
      return;
    }
  }
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return !(this.isDataChanged == true);
  }

  //Host Listner for Up and Down Arrow (KeyboardEvent)
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.showDropdownEle(event);
  }

    onCurrentSnapshotPeriodChange = ($event: any) => {
        if (this.isDataChanged == true) {
          debugger
          var z = event.returnValue;
         // $event.returnValue =
        //  this.confirmationDialogService
    //    return

        }else{
        this.periodName = $event.periodName;
        this.hasValuation = true;
        //refresh the page with new period
        this.getDealFinancialMetrics();
        }
```

so here i am checking if data is changed or not but i am unable to revert back to previous selection that is for example if there are A,B,C,D as option in dropdown and by default i see as A been selected if i make any changes in the textbox and then when i try to click on B from dropdown menu i should not be able to go to B until i dont click on save button and a popup should appear saying would you like to save the changes with ok and cancel button. if i click on cancel then i should be still in the dropdown menu A and if i click on ok button then i should be in dropdown menu b.

Comment: Could please post your entire component class?

Comment: @RafiHenig i have added

Comment: can anyone help me with setting the drop down value to previous value?

Answer (score 0):

See this StackBlitz link [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcqrji)

you can use @ViewChild for getting changed value of dropdown and textbox. then you need one object for reference. Object structure is like this..

```
textChangeValue ={
   changed : false,
   dropdownValue: '',
   previousTextValue:'',
   currentTextValue:'',
   saveValue:{
      saveDropdownValue: '',
      saveTextValue:''
   }
};
```

Your onChange dropdown looks like this...

```
onChange(value){
    if ((this.selectDropdown.nativeElement.value !== this.selectText.nativeElement.value) && (this.textChangeValue.changed !==  false) ){
      let confirmValue =  confirm('Do you want to save change');
        if (confirmValue){
          this.save();
          this.textChangeValue.dropdownValue= this.selectDropdown.nativeElement.value;
          this.selectText.nativeElement.value = 
          this.selectDropdown.nativeElement.value;
        }
      else{
          this.selectDropdown.nativeElement.value = this.textChangeValue.dropdownValue;
          this.selectText.nativeElement.value = this.textChangeValue.currentTextValue;
      }
}else{
      this.selectText.nativeElement.value = value
      this.textChangeValue.currentTextValue = value;
      this.textChangeValue.dropdownValue = value;
}
}
```

your html template looks like this...

```
<select #selectDropdown  (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<input #selectText type="text" (change)="onTextChange($event)">
```